# Gcc hidden Members in struct

Tags: c, gcc, struct, hidden

Currently, I am working with an embedded device.

I am creating my own "register representation" to learn the process in the C Language.

I do this via structs placed at given locations:

```
struct myIo {
   u32 flagA : 1;
   u32 fieldB : 7;
   u32 reserved : 24;
   u32 regB;
};

struct __attribute__((section("sec"))) myIo MyIo;
```

This works just fine and all, but I wonder how I could remove the

```
reserved
```

fields without compromising the padding/alignment enforced by the hardware.

**My question is:**

How could I design a struct with "hidden" fields, that won't show up when I access the struct.

In essence:

```
MyStruct.reserved = val;
```

or

```
val = MyStruct.reserved;
```

should throw a compiler error and typing

```
MyIo.
```

should not bring up "Auto-Complete" options in Eclipse CDT C/C++.

I am using Arm Cross GCC and Eclipse CDT C/C++.

I am good with C-Standard compliant solutions, compiler pragma solutions and preprocessor solutions.

Comment: Simply remove `reserved` — unless you pack the structure (don't!), the `regB` will be properly aligned.  Alternatively, replace `reserved` by `u32 : 0;` to force alignment into the next storage unit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why not pack the structure? Could you please explain?

Comment: If you pack the structure, the alignment of `RegB` is no longer guaranteed (to the extent anything is ever guaranteed with bit-fields — they are very much 'implementation defined').  If you have the explicit `reserved` member, or if you have an anonymous 24-bit bit-field, then you'd be OK.  But dropping the bit-field and packing the structure would leave the compiler able to align `RegB` immediately after the 8-bits reserved by name.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for clarifying. You mentioned, that bit-fields tend to cause problems due to implementation defined behaviour. Can you explain what you mean with this please?

Comment: The rules for bit-fields laid out by the standard are very — flexible.  Many properties are implementation-defined.  Consequently, writing portable code that uses bit-fields is hard.  You need to carefully isolate bit-field definitions so that you can adapt to the actual implementation you're using.  See C11 [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1) for most of the sordid details — but also [§3.14](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.14) and [§6.2.6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6). Note: in theory, `u32` might not be valid…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an unnamed bitfield:

```
struct myIo {
   u32 flagA : 1;
   u32 fieldB : 7;
   u32 : 24;
   u32 regB;
};
```

Such constructs are allowed as per section 6.7.2.1p12 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding "Structure and union specifiers":

> A bit-field declaration with no declarator, but only a colon and a
> width, indicates an unnamed bit-field. <sup>126)</sup> As a special
> case, a bit-field structure member with a width of 0 indicates that no
> further bit-field is to be packed into the unit in which the previous
> bit- field, if any, was placed.
>
> ---
>
> 126 ) An unnamed bit-field structure member is useful for padding to
> conform to externally imposed layouts.

Note that a zero-sized bitfield will also work in this case, but only because no other bitfields follow it.

Comment: And `u32 : 0;` would also work.

Comment: @dbush Thank you fine Sir! Solved my issues in no time.

Comment: can you make it clear if this is gcc specific or standard c

Comment: This is Standard C, @pm100.